# FluentValidation RuleFor attribute of Foreign Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

When I run the program I get a System.NullReferenceException on `x.Album.Title == "Disintegration"` in:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Contents)
            .NotNull()
            .When(x => x.Album.Title == "Disintegration");
```

How can I program this so that `Contents` is not accepted as Null when `Album.Title == "Disintegration`?

Model

```
[Validator(typeof(ReviewValidation))]
public class Review
{
    public int ReviewID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Album")]
    public int AlbumID { get; set; }

    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }

    public string Contents { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string ReviewerEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Validation

```
public class ReviewValidation : AbstractValidator<Review>
{
    public ReviewValidation()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Contents)
            .NotNull()
            .When(x => x.Album.Title == "Disintegration");
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class ReviewsController : Controller
{
    private StoreContext db = new StoreContext();
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.AlbumID = new SelectList(db.Albums, "AlbumID", "Title");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Review review)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Reviews.Add(review);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.AlbumID = new SelectList(db.Albums, "AlbumID", "Title", review.AlbumID);
        return View(review);
    }
}
```

View

```
@model MVCMusicStore.Models.Review


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Review</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlbumID, "AlbumID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("AlbumID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlbumID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contents, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contents, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contents, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReviewerEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReviewerEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReviewerEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your view needs to pass the Album.Title back to the POST action in order to validate it. At the moment (from the code you posted), the Album property is null since it was never assigned an actual album, then in the view code where you post to the action, you didn't include the title.

Anyway, the exception you are getting is because Album prop is null in your code, and you are trying to validate its title.

What you could do also is to change the validation code, to only validate when album is not null

```
When(x => x.Album != null, () => 
{
     RuleFor(x => x.Contents).NotNull().When(x => x.Album.Title == "Disintegration");
});
```